# Changes mysql to mysqli and its xampp version

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

If I change my code from mysql to mysqli, should I changes the xampp version too?my xampp version is 2.5.8.

Because after I changed them, many errors occurred and all the errors pointing to the 'mysqli' such as :

```
  mysqli_prepare()
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param()
  mysqli_stmt_execute()
  mysqli_num_rows()
```

connection.php

```
<?php

session_start();
// *Peringatan jangan ubah fail ni..        
$dbhost = "localhost"; //server untuk test
$dbuser = "root"; //user MYSQL
$dbpass = ""; //password MYSQL
$db = "sukandb"; //nama database
//tapi bila masuk ke dalam server kena tukar ikut keadaan server

$conn = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

if($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection failed : " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
?>
```

All the errors are in this file :
index.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("connection.php");
if($_SESSION['LoggedIn']): 
echo "Hello " .$_SESSION['nama'];
endif; 

$query = mysqli_prepare("SELECT * FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE noic = ? AND 
katalaluan = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, $_POST["noic"],md5($_POST["katalaluan"]));
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$_SESSION['userdetail']=$query;
$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['nama'] = $result["nama"];
header("location:carianstatuspemohonresult.php");
exit;
 }
 else
  {
    echo "Salah nombor IC dan kata laluan";

}
?>
```

Comment: Would you please post your error message.

Comment: Sure.                                                                                             Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in 

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: That is not how you use prepared statement and how to get the number of rows.

Comment: @LoganWayne which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mysqli_query()` would be looking for your database connection on the first parameter:

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT userdetail, nama FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE noic = ? AND katalaluan = ?");
```

Change the binding part to

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ss", $_POST["noic"], md5($_POST["katalaluan"]));
```

Then get the result:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $userdetail, $nama);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($query);
```

Refer also [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to learn more about `mysqli_*` prepared statement.

Also use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to store password more securely.

Comment: this answer is only useful for the OP, but of no use for anyone else. Given the OP will accept this, it will do more harm than good. Just a thought.

Comment: @YourCommonSense so should I use Logan Wayne solution?

Comment: @iladila My answer will solve your current situation, but YourCommonSense is talking about a broader scope

Answer (score 0):

No you dont have to change your xampp. As soon as you are using PHP 5 `mysqli` will work fine.


First of all you need to know about xampp, actually xampp is nothing but a bundle of **PHP**, **MySQL** and **Apache** primarily (But with more options and servers).
You need to check your PHP version provided by your `XAMPP`. To check your PHP version go to your XAMPP Control panel and run shell and then type following command

```
php -v
```

if your PHP version something like 5.* then you are go to go from **MySQL** to **MySQLi**

The mysqli extension is designed to work with MySQL version 4.1.13 or newer, or 5.0.7 or newer.
The mysqli extension was introduced with PHP version 5.0.0. The MySQL Native Driver was included in PHP version 5.3.0. 
 
Check your versions and decide whether to change or not.

**Update:** Provide your `$conn` to your statement (prepare method).

Comment: I've already check the php version. it's PHP 5.3.1 .but the errors make me confused

Comment: Sorry I'm late. I'm using PHPMYADMIN.  it's version is 3.2.4 .Is this the one of my problem too?

Comment: why dont you install new xampp ??? and see if you get the error or not.

Comment: errmmm the mysql server version: 5.1.41, the MySQL client version: 5.1.41

Comment: I've started the newest xampp. it's same error also

Comment: Guys, why are you still discussing on versions etc? If anyone of you would have looked at the code, you would have seen in 1 minute that he has syntax errors in his statements.

Comment: @Twinfriends can u tell me which statement is wrong?

Comment: The prepare / bind_params part. Google for it, you'll find a lot of examples.